# Express JS query Error Handling not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

this is my first post on Stackoverflow, so please be kind.

I have a huge problem, which I couldn't fix by googling (which is pretty rare).
I want to create a simple error handling in my query, but it won't work.

Here's the code:

```
pool.query("SELECT password_hash FROM User WHERE email = ?",
    req.body.EMailLogin, (error, results, fields) => {
      
      if(error) {
        // It executes the if aswell as the else statement and I dont know why (if(error) seems to be ignored even if its true)
      } else {
        // And then it crashes here, because password_hash is undefined
        let hash = results[0].password_hash;
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.PasswordLogin, hash, function(err, result) {
          if (result == true) {
            ses.user = req.body.EMailLogin;
            req.session.cookie.expires = false;
            req.session.save(() => {
              return res.redirect('/index');
            });
          } else {
            res.render(); // My Page for Wrong Password (ignore this)
          }
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to check weather query return data or not and also you can pass values either using object or array(in your case, should be array)

```
pool.query("SELECT password_hash FROM User WHERE email = ?", [req.body.EMailLogin],
    (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            // any error like wrong query, connection closed, etc.
            // It executes the if aswell as the else statement and I dont know why (if(error) seems to be ignored even if its true)
        } else if (results.length === 0) {
            // email not found in database
            // My Page for Wrong Email ???
        }   else {
            // And then it crashes here, because password_hash is undefined
            let hash = results[0].password_hash;
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.PasswordLogin, hash, function (err, result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    ses.user = req.body.EMailLogin;
                    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
                    req.session.save(() => {
                        return res.redirect('/index');
                    });
                } else {
                    res.render(); // My Page for Wrong Password (ignore this)
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

`Throw` the error inside the if

```
if(error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
```

I think that the error is how you're passing the parameter, it should be an array:

```
pool.query("SELECT password_hash FROM User WHERE email = ?",
    [req.body.EMailLogin],
```

I hope this fixes your problem.